# Google Sheets editing sheet based off of checkmark boxes

Tags: google-apps-script

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Usxx3aWixm3_XVsfbpg3Wxgsfp5RsjaVR-ksPVzJco8/edit?usp=sharing)

I have sheet2 setup with a complete list of work orders in column A. In column B I have a simple marker of 'TRUE' to signify the work is done. In sheet1 I have a filter to only display orders that are not marked 'TRUE' in column B from sheet2. Next to the list of orders in sheet1 are checkboxes. I would like a script that can read when a checkbox is marked, read what the item is next to the checkbox, mark the checkbox 'FALSE' to clear it, then mark the appropriate row in column B from sheet2 as 'TRUE' so the item leaves the list on sheet1.

I'll set the script up using an 'On edit' trigger, but I need help with creating the script that can do those function.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I honestly don't know where to start besides loading the sheet.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

Comment: To get started, you can try checking out the examples written in the [guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets). There are examples on how to read and write data to Sheets. For further guides, you can check out the [Sheets documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts).

Answer (score 0):

after much searching and self debugging I came up with this. Does this look ok? I'm going to be placing this in a spreadsheet with many thousands of entries. I don't want it to be horribly inefficient.

```
function MarkComplete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();                //Loading Current spreadsheet
  var Display = ss.getSheetByName("Display");         //Loading Display sheet
  var Complete = ss.getSheetByName("Complete");       //Loading Complete sheet
  var data1 = Display.getDataRange().getValues();     //Loading data from sheet 1
  var data2 = Complete.getDataRange().getValues();    //Loading data from sheet 2

  for(var i = 0; i<data1.length;i++){
    Logger.log('List item : ' + data1[i][0]);
    Logger.log('Checked : ' + data1[i][1]);         

    if(data1[i][1] == true){                        //Looking for rows in Display that are checked.
      Logger.log('TRUE : ' + data1[i][0]);

      for(var n = 0; n<data2.length;n++){ 
        if(data2[n][0] == data1[i][0]){               //Looking for rows in Complete that match checked rows in Display
          Complete.getRange(n+1,2).setValue("=true");    //set row x column 2 to true in complete
          Display.getRange(i+1,2).setValue("false");    //set row i column 2 to false in display
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```